How to iterate through multi-dimensional arrays in expl3
In the past I have already worked with one-dimensional arrays or better sequences in expl3. At the end I have summarized all my array handling functions in this question.
But in the past, I only used one-dimensional arrays and these arrays were created "dynamically" while compile time. I have never defined a fixed array with dedicated entries, I just used an \appendElement function to dynamically add new elements.
Now that this type of array processing works, I'm shifting my focus to using arrays as configuration structures. Therefore, they should store important information for different types of items. In my case, these elements are various electrical components for a SmartHome installation, but this shouldn't matter at this point.
I tried to abstract my example as much and as good as I can, to focus on the important topics. Of course my real environment consists of even more and even bigger arrays then used here in this MWE.
The MWE I have given is written by me in LaTeX2e and works as expected. But as you can see the syntax especially the inflationary use of \noexpand makes the code nearly unreadable and on top of that I bet, that I could participate from some other great improvements when switching to expl3 ;)
Code Explanation
The clue in the following code is, that there is a huge "master" list with different types of elements (data.csv). In my real environment these types differ in their functionality, there allowed order, their defined properties and so on but in this MWE they just differ in the Type itself and the Description they are storing.
Next to the master list there are is a matching array element for every Type within the first sub array from \mainArray.
\def\mainArray{
{\noexpand\firstArrayA},{\noexpand\secondArrayA},{\noexpand\thirdArrayA},...
}
In this case \firstArrayA belongs to TypA, \firstArrayB belongs to TypB and so on.
For all types there is more than one "configuration" array (\firstArrayX, \secondArrayX, \thirdArrayX). And these different arrays are summarized within the \mainArray. So at least I have a bundle of different arrays belonging to one dedicated Type.
The task is now to get / temporarily store all of these type depending data and work with them in the next step.
The \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{Type}\of{\csvdata}\as{\columnType}is just there to iterate through the whole list of elements and find the matching type within the \mainArray.
Now my questions

Is it possible to translate this MWE into expl3 and could someone give me and proposal? In this case a good readable example counts more than a high efficient one.
When this is possible it would be great to use the Feature in expl3, to define two input parameters (#2 / #3) which are called, when the defined Type was NOT found [#2] (so I can react on this wrong input data) or the other way, when the Type was found [#3] (after storing all properties of course).

Working MWE in LaTex2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% Modulo operations
\def\truncdiv#1#2{((#1-(#2-1)/2)/#2)}
\def\moduloop#1#2{(#1-\truncdiv{#1}{#2}*#2)}
\def\modulo#1#2{\number\numexpr\moduloop{#1}{#2}\relax}

% Global variables
\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{counterB}
\newcommand{\foundInArray}{false}

% Define input data
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
   Type,Description
   TypA,Here TypeA
   TypB,Here TypeB
   TypB,Here TypeB
   TypC,Here TypeC
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}

% Define table style
\pgfplotstableset{
   verb string type,
   every head row/.append style={
      before row={\hline},
      after row={\hline}
   },
}

% First Array
\def\firstArrayA{TypA}
\def\firstArrayB{TypB}
\def\firstArrayC{TypC}

% Second Array
\def\secondArrayA{{SecondA1},{SecondA2},{SecondA3}}
\def\secondArrayB{{SecondB1},{SecondB2},{SecondB3}}
\def\secondArrayC{{SecondC1},{SecondC2},{SecondC3}}

% Third Array
\def\thirdArrayA{{ThirdA1},{ThirdA2},{ThirdA3}}
\def\thirdArrayB{{ThirdB1},{ThirdB2},{ThirdB3}}
\def\thirdArrayC{{ThirdC1},{ThirdC2},{ThirdC3}}

% Main / Combined Array
\def\mainArray{
  {\noexpand\firstArrayA},{\noexpand\secondArrayA},{\noexpand\thirdArrayA},
  {\noexpand\firstArrayB},{\noexpand\secondArrayB},{\noexpand\thirdArrayB},
  {\noexpand\firstArrayC},{\noexpand\secondArrayC},{\noexpand\thirdArrayC},
}

\newcommand{\searchForElements}[1]{% \mainArray     
  \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{Type}\of{\csvdata}\as{\columnType}{
    \setcounter{counterA}{0}
    \foreach \elementA in #1 {
      \stepcounter{counterA}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\modulo{\value{counterA}}{3}}{1}}{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\columnType}{\expanded{\elementA}}}{
          \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\foundInArray\expandafter{true}
        }{}
      }{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\foundInArray}{true}}{
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\modulo{\value{counterA}}{3}}{2}}{
            \setcounter{counterB}{1}
            \begingroup
            \edef\temp{\endgroup
              \noexpand\foreach \noexpand\elementB in \elementA {
                \noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{\noexpand\the\value{counterB}}{1}}{
                  % Temporarily store the data
                  \noexpand\elementB\\
                }{}
                \noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{\noexpand\the\value{counterB}}{2}}{
                  % Temporarily store the data
                  \noexpand\elementB\\
                }{}
                \noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{\noexpand\the\value{counterB}}{3}}{
                  % Temporarily store the data
                  \noexpand\elementB\\
                }{}
                \noexpand\stepcounter{counterB}
              }
            }\temp
          }{}
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\modulo{\value{counterA}}{3}}{0}}{
            \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\foundInArray\expandafter{false}
            \setcounter{counterB}{1}
            \begingroup
            \edef\temp{\endgroup
              \noexpand\foreach \noexpand\elementB in \elementA {
                \noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{\noexpand\the\value{counterB}}{1}}{
                  % Temporarily store the data
                  \noexpand\elementB\\
                }{}
                \noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{\noexpand\the\value{counterB}}{2}}{
                  % Temporarily store the data
                  \noexpand\elementB\\
                }{}
                \noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{\noexpand\the\value{counterB}}{3}}{
                  % Temporarily store the data
                  \noexpand\elementB\\
                }{}
                \noexpand\stepcounter{counterB}
              }
            }\temp
          }{}       
        }{}
      }
    }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Please define the expl3 routine here...
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\textbf{RAW DATA}\\
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}\vspace{10mm}\\
\textbf{SEARCH RESULTS}\\
\searchForElements{\mainArray}\\
\end{document}

CURRENT / EXPECTED OUTPUT

EDIT 1
I tried to explain it as best as I can, but it still seems to be not understandable. The searchForElements function searches within the \mainArray => \firstArrayX (counterA mod 3 == 1) if the \columnType from \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{Type}\of{\csvdata}\as{\columnType} is part of the array or not. If the Type could be found, then all data are read and temporarily stored (the storing process is not shown in the MWE). If there is no matching Type then nothing could be read of course. In this case \foundInArray is never set to true and counterA mod 3 == 2 / 0 is never tested.  This is basically what the shown LaTeX2 routine does. My question is to translate this behavior in expl3. As add-on I only ask to use the expl3 feature that we can choose different paths after processing the before described function. So in case the Type is NOT found I want to follow the first path (given as input variable #2) and in case the Type is found and all variables are stored I want to follow the other path (given as input variable #3).
An additional hint to the given arrays. The big difference between this question and my questions before regarding arrays is that in this case I want to define static arrays. There is no need to change these arrays while compile time e.g. with \appendElement or \removeElement rountines. Additionally in this case I merge more than one array as you can see. My \mainArray consists of three different array types (arrays with different lengths).

why are you using \edef and \noexpand everywhere? It makes your code very hard to follow

@DavidCarlisle I feel the same, but did not found another way to achieve the nested \foreach loops.

but you have the advantage of knowing what you intend this to do, whereas you are expecting us to read this and guess the intent. Your searchForElements doesn't seem to be a search just listing all the elements in sequence, is that all you need?

why are you back with your arrays in tex/2e and asking for conversion to expl3? you've got a whole bunch of answers implementing bits of things to do with arrays, many in expl3, bu you keep coming back to tex/2e. that's not a problem, except you keep putting it back into tex/2e and then asking for conversion again to expl3. why don't you just code it in expl3? I don't see how you can hope to get this all working together using this method. if you want to use expl3, use expl3 and ask if you get stuck. if you want to use something else, use something else.

@DavidCarlisle I added additional information to the end of my question. Hopefully this clarifies what I mean.

@cfr My problem is, that when I decided to use expl3 all these constructs were already there and now I stuck at some points converting my code to expl3. For me two parts are new here and not covered in my questions before. 1. I want to define static arrays. There is no need to change these arrays while compile time e.g. with \appendElement or \removeElement routines. 2. In this example I use a \mainArray which consists of three different array types (arrays with different length). This is also new for me.

I have some annotations and questions, so I took the freedom to creata a chat room

@UlrichDiez Thanks for creating this. I have summarized more background infos there.

It's not really clear what you intend to do here but this is a nested list of lists and a double iteration that shows them as a tabular done as a nested clist_map_inline

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_const:Nn\l_array_main_clist
{ {a1,a2,a3},
  {b1,b2,b3},
  {c1,c2,c3}
}

\tl_new:N\g_array_newline_tl

\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
  h1&h2&h3\\
  \hline
\clist_map_inline:Nn
\l_array_main_clist
  {\g_array_newline_tl
   \tl_gset:Nn \g_array_newline_tl{\\}
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}{##1&}}
\end{tabular}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\end{document}


In comments it appears your main concern is the outer list should have references to the inner list not be expanded out. I show that below, it makes identical output, the only differemce is that the inner iteration uses the N form to map over the value of the referenced list rather than the n form.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_const:Nn\l_array_a_clist {a1,a2,a3}
\clist_const:Nn\l_array_b_clist {b1,b2,b3}
\clist_const:Nn\l_array_c_clist {c1,c2,c3}
\clist_const:Nn\l_array_main_clist
{\l_array_a_clist ,
 \l_array_b_clist,
 \l_array_c_clist
}

\tl_new:N\g_array_newline_tl

\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
  h1&h2&h3\\
  \hline
\clist_map_inline:Nn
\l_array_main_clist
  {\g_array_newline_tl
   \tl_gset:Nn \g_array_newline_tl{\\}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1 {##1&}}
\end{tabular}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\end{document}


+1 for "It's not really clear what you intend to do here"

Unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue, please see my edits in the question.

@Pascal well it exactly solves the question in the titlee. As I commented, it was basically impossible to get further information from the original question, but I'll have a look at your edit.

Thanks! I also added some more background information within the chat room.

@Pascal updated answer

@DavidCarlisle Got it now! Thanks for pushing me in the right direction. To show what I wanted to achieve in the end, I put it in a separate answer.

After a lot of hints and chat room discussions I finally reached my goal with the following code. Maybe this will help someone else in the future to handle iterating through nested arrays.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Type,Description
    TypA,Here TypeA
    TypB,Here TypeB
    TypB,Here TypeB
    TypC,Here TypeC
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstableset{
   verb string type,
   every head row/.append style={
      before row={\hline},
      after row={\hline}
   },
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_first_a_clist {TypA}
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_first_b_clist {TypB}
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_first_c_clist {TypC}
    
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_second_a_clist {SecondA1,SecondA2,SecondA3}
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_second_b_clist {SecondB1,SecondB2,SecondB3}
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_second_c_clist {SecondC1,SecondC2,SecondC3}
    
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_third_a_clist {ThirdA1,ThirdA2,ThirdA3}
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_third_b_clist {ThirdB1,ThirdB2,ThirdB3}
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_third_c_clist {ThirdC1,ThirdC2,ThirdC3}
    
\clist_const:Nn\c_pascal_array_main_clist
{
    \c_pascal_array_first_a_clist,\c_pascal_array_second_a_clist,\c_pascal_array_third_a_clist,
    \c_pascal_array_first_b_clist,\c_pascal_array_second_b_clist,\c_pascal_array_third_b_clist,
    \c_pascal_array_first_c_clist,\c_pascal_array_second_c_clist,\c_pascal_array_third_c_clist,
}

\int_new:N \l_pascal_element_counter_int
\int_new:N \l_pascal_sub_element_counter_int

\bool_new:N \l_pascal_componentFound_var_bool
\bool_new:N \l_pascal_break_flag_var_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\iterateThroughArray}{mmm}
{
    \bool_set_false:N \l_pascal_break_flag_var_bool
    \bool_set_false:N \l_pascal_componentFound_var_bool    
    \int_zero:N \l_pascal_element_counter_int
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \c_pascal_array_main_clist {
        \bool_if:NT \l_pascal_break_flag_var_bool {\clist_map_break:}
        \int_incr:N \l_pascal_element_counter_int
        \int_zero:N \l_pascal_sub_element_counter_int
        \clist_map_inline:Nn ##1 {
            \int_incr:N \l_pascal_sub_element_counter_int
            \int_compare:nNnT {\int_mod:nn {\l_pascal_element_counter_int} {3}} {=} {1}
            {
                 \tl_set:Ne \typeVar {####1}
            }
            \str_if_eq:eeT {\typeVar} {#1}
            {
                \bool_set_true:N \l_pascal_componentFound_var_bool
                \int_compare:nNnT {\int_mod:nn {\l_pascal_element_counter_int} {3}} {=} {2}
                {
                    \int_case:nnF {\l_pascal_sub_element_counter_int}
                    {
                      {1} { \tl_set:Ne \secondOne {####1}}
                      {2} { \tl_set:Ne \secondTwo {####1}}
                      {3} { \tl_set:Ne \secondThree {####1}}
                    }
                    { Undefined sub-array element! }
                }
                \int_compare:nNnT {\int_mod:nn {\l_pascal_element_counter_int} {3}} {=} {0}
                {
                    \int_case:nnF {\l_pascal_sub_element_counter_int}
                    {
                      {1} { \tl_set:Ne \thirdOne {####1}}
                      {2} { \tl_set:Ne \thirdTwo {####1}}
                      {3} { \tl_set:Ne \thirdThree {####1}
                        \bool_set_true:N \l_pascal_break_flag_var_bool }
                    }
                    { Undefined sub-array element! }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    \bool_if:NTF \l_pascal_componentFound_var_bool {#2}{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{Type}\of{\csvdata}\as{\columnType}{
        \iterateThroughArray{\columnType}{
            \typeVar\\
            \secondOne\\
            \secondTwo\\
            \secondThree\\
            \thirdOne\\
            \thirdTwo\\
            \thirdThree\\
        }{Component not found!\\}
    }
\end{document}

OUTPUT


thanks for showing what you came up with, but you should correct this if you want to post it as an example ;). constants should begin \c_ not \l_ and you should use a common module prefix in all functions and variables e.g. \c_pascal_array_third_clist or whatever. they should all end with the relevant type suffix. so not \l_type_var but \l_pascal_type_var_tl or whatever. but you could just say \tl_set:Ne \typeVar {####1} if you're only setting the token list in order to then create an l2 command. you could also use booleans rather than testing strings.

@cfr Edited it accordingly to your comments! And also replaced \int_compare: with \int_case:.
